# I can't find where to turn off grammar issues highlighting in Chrome; where is it in Settings? I don't see it under Languages

Tags: google-chrome, chromebook, grammar

I can't find where to turn off grammatical ssues highlighting in Chrome. Where is it in Settings? I don't see it under Languages, where advice I've found online says to look for it.

Comment: *do you see an option in Settings > Languages & Inputs called “Spell Check” or “Spelling and grammar check” ?*

Comment: Found it under "Inputs and keyboards".

Answer (score 0):

Grammar check in Chrome is usually furnished by extensions.

Enter `chrome://extensions` in the address bar and look for a grammar
extension. You may disable it by clicking on the blue slide, or click
Remove to uninstall the extension.

If you would also like to disable
[Chrome spell](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/12027911?hl=en),
this is done in *Settings > Advanced > Languages*, by clicking on
the slide to the right of "Spell check".

Comment: I don't see anything relating to grammar extensions. I'm on a Chromebook, if that makes a difference? I've added the chromebook tag.

Comment: My answer was for Chrome. I don't have experience with the Chromebook, but do you see an option in *Settings > Languages & Inputs* called “Spell Check”  or “Spelling and grammar check” ? It may be an OS option.